# wxPython flat GenButton border

Tags: python, button, user-interface, wxpython

I am designing a GUI using wxPython with flat buttons.

How can I make a thin border around the button, like button2 in the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYo0D.png

The button that I have now looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz3r8.png

The code:

```
    import wx.lib.buttons as buttons
    [...]
    self.a = buttons.GenButton(self, 00, "0", (140, 380), size=(100, 100),style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
    self.a.SetBackgroundColour((215, 215, 215))
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: A link to a similar post :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922769/how-to-add-an-outline-border-to-a-widget

Comment: Thank you! :) This means, that there is no way to make it to the GenButton?

Comment: I would recommand not to hardcode id's, use wx.ID_ANY instead.  Similar for size and position I would recommend to use sizers.

Answer (score 1):

With GenButton this should work:

```
buttons.GenButton(pane, wx.ID_ANY, "1", wx.DefaultPosition, size=(100, 100),
                  style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
```

or:

```
buttons.ThemedGenButton(pane, wx.ID_ANY, 'Themed - Drawn with native renderer')
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I want, but then the button is not flat anymore... 
I don't want the '3D' effect around the button.

Comment: See above, you might want to check in the wxPython demo for more options.